# Realm Java - Ordering/filtering list of 2 combined Realm Object Models with a one to many relationship

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, realm-list, realm-java

I am trying to display an ordered/filtered List (via RealmBaseAdapter or RealmRecyclerViewAdapter) of a combination of 2 Realm Objects. Here are my realm Object classes:

first object:

```
public class TaskModel implements RealmModel {
@Required
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
@Required
private String name;
private Date dueDate;
private String category

private RealmList<SubTaskModel> subTasks;

......getters and setters
}
```

second object:

```
public class SubTaskModel implements RealmModel {
@Required
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
@Required
private String name;
private Date dueDate;
private String category

TaskModel task;

......getters and setters
}
```

My "Task" and "Subtask" Objects is a one-to-many relationship which is why I modelled them in separate Object classes. What I want to do is display a combined list of Task and SubTasks and order them by Due date. I also have a requirement to  sort by name and filter(search) by category and name. I.e.

- Task 1 -due date Jan 1st
- Task 2 - due date Jan 5th
- SubTask 1 -due date Jan 2nd
- SubTask 2 - due date Jan 3rd

The returned ordered list should be:

- Task1
- SubTask1
- SubTask2
- Task2

I was inclined to [follow this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44094177/9209770), but wanted to make sure this was the best solution in terms of performance and best practices. From what I gather, I would have to create another Object Class, lets say "AllTasks" and everytime I create a Task or SubTasks object I would have to create a AllTasks Object linking to them here. Also, anytime I update the name, category and Date fields in either SubTasks and/or Tasks I would have to update the AllTasks object with the same fields. Want to make sure there isn't a better way to achieve my requirements (I.e. will have to remember to update 2 objects everytime, which isn't ideal).

```java
public class AllTasks extends RealmObject {
private static final int ENTRY_TASK = 0;
private static final int ENTRY_SUBTASK = 1;


/** The tag describes what kind of entry it represents */
private int tag;

/* Only one of these can be set, according to what this entry represents. */
@Nullable private TaskModel task;
@Nullable private SubTaskModel subTask;



private Date date;
private String name;
private String category;

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

  /* Can only be accessed from within the 'data' package */

void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

......other getter and setters

static AllTasks createAsTask(@NonNull final Realm realm, @NonNull 
final TaskModel task) {
    if(realm == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'realm' may not be null");
    }
    if(mtask == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'task' may not be 
  null");
    }

    AllTasks entry = realm.createObject(AllTasks.class);
    entry.tag = ENTRY_TASK;
    entry.task = task;
    return entry;
    }
...repeat above method for SubTasks

  }
```

Comment: `My "Task" and "Subtask" Objects is a one-to-many relationship which is why I modelled them in separate Object classes.` why not just have it as  `TaskModel` and `RealmList<TaskModel>`?

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion @EpicPandaForce ! I didn't think of that . I think that"ll work, will try it out. Just thinking out loud here -In parts of my program I need to display subtasks differently than tasks, so in addition to the solution above I would need to create a couple extra fields to differentiate between a task and subtask and also a handle on the parent tasks name ( IsChild, setParent ,getParent.getName()). Does that make sense? Thanks again for your suggestion, much appreciated!

Comment: I used to have a `parentId` which was `null` for the roots. So anything that was `.isNotNull("parentId")` was a subtask

Comment: Perfect, even better.

Comment: I implemented the solution above and it worked beautifully, thanks again!